# Form validation (radio & combobox) in javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox, radio-button, validation

I am trying to validate radiobuttons and optionbox in javascript. Here is the code but it is not working...
Javascript Code for OprionBox and Radio:

```
function checkCountry()
        {
        if(document.form.country.selectedIndex=="")
        {
        alert("Please select country from the list");
        return false;  
        }
        return true
        }
function checkGender()
        {
        if(!document.getElementsByName("sex")[0].checked && !document.getElementsByName("sex")[1].checked)
        {
        alert("Select Male/Female");
        return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
function validate()
      {
            checkCountry();
            checkGender();
      }
```

HTML code:

```
<form name="form" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">                
    <select name="country">
    <option value="select">(Please select a country)</option>
    <option value="pk">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="chn">China</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
    <option value="ir">Iran</option>
    <option value="ma">Malaysia</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female<br></form>
```

Please help...

Comment: You did not say anything about WHAT is going wrong here. "It's not working" and "Please Help" is not a question. Please try to form a more detailed question.

Comment: What I actually need is that when I leave these form components empty, it should display alert error message... But it's not.

Comment: Please try to understand document model of HTML before trying to do validations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the line where you check for the selected index to:

`if(document.form.country.selectedIndex === 0)` thats because of your "Please select a country" entry you will always have a selected index.

If i then add `<input type="submit" value="test"/>` inside your form to test submitting i will get your error messages.

Please see http://jsbin.com/oviped/2/edit it is working!

Comment: It's the same again... Isn't giving error message when I do not select any country.

Comment: I edited my answer please see the link. I tried it and it is definetly working.

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(document.form.country.selectedIndex=="")` to `if(document.getElementsByName("country").selectedIndex=="0")`

Comment: I copied your line as it was but no result again.

Answer (score 0):

This is whole code and its working fine

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkGender()
        {
        if(!document.getElementsByName("sex")[0].checked && !document.getElementsByName("sex")[1].checked)
        {
        alert("Select Male/Female");
        return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
function checkCountry()
        {

      if(document.getElementsByName("country")[0].selectedIndex==0)
        {
        alert("Please select country from the list");
        return false;  
        }
        return true
        }
function validate()
      {
            checkCountry();
           checkGender();
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form onSubmit="return validate()" >
  <select name="country">
    <option value="select">(Please select a country)</option>
    <option value="pk">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="chn">China</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
    <option value="ir">Iran</option>
    <option value="ma">Malaysia</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```